# Shopify search engine add-on

Tags: shopify

I'm working on a search engine add-on.

Is it possible to add my search engine add-on into shopify frontpage?

I have research http://www.searchifyapp.com, how they can customize shopify search page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with searchifyapp.com, so I won't tell you how it works, but I can tell you how it could be done.

If you want to have the shop's data indexed on your search server, then you will want to import the data from shopify on installation and use webhooks for updates.  The [Syncing with a Store](http://wiki.shopify.com/Syncing_with_a_Store) Shopify Wiki page explains how this is done.

You can use [ScriptTags](http://api.shopify.com/scripttag.html) to inject javascript into the storefront. Then the javascript can find and enhance/modify the search field/form (e.g. for autocompletion/suggestions as they type, or modify the url for the search results page).

If you want to custom search results (e.g. from your own search server), then you could create an [Application Proxy](http://api.shopify.com/app_proxy.html) to serve results from your own web application.

Comment: Hi, i have read your documentation http://api.shopify.com/app_proxy.html, it doesn't work correctly, shopify give an error message "Temporary problem - We're experiencing a technical problem and we are doing everything we can to resolve it as soon as possible."

Comment: I checked and our api-proxy appears to be working.  Do you have a url, or steps to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I have solved the problem. My server in singapore, and I think shopify server is in US so that makes connection time out between the server. Thanks